# How to get scaled size of HTML canvas when using object-fit CSS property

Tags: javascript, html, css

When using the CSS `object-fit: contain` option to scale the contents of a canvas while maintaining aspect ratio, how do you get the visible pixel dimensions of the canvas after scaling, not including letterbox?

`canvas.height` & `canvas.width` give the native resolution of the canvas, and `canvas.clientHeight` & `canvas.clientWidth` give the pixel dimensions of the "whole" canvas, including the letterbox bars above and below the scaled area.

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbreeden86/zwrawowo/) shows a scaled `<canvas>` inside a larger `<div>`, and shows which sizes are being returned. In this instance, I'd like a property that returns a width and height of 300. Does such a property exist?

My application needs to use the other `object-fit` modes as well, so I need a solution that works for any (specifically `fill` or `none`). I'd like to avoid switching on the object-fit mode and writing the logic to calculate the size myself if I can.